# DHCP Leases (8 days) expiring more than once a day. (Windows Server DHCP)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp, dhcp-server

First of all, I'm sorry if I'm posting this to the wrong place. I'm new here so I am still getting used to how the site works!

We have a DHCP server and the scope lease is set to 8 days, but we found that some machine leases are expiring more than once a day, apparently for no reason. This is happening to many leases in different scopes.

Here are some pieces of the DHCP audit log: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXZ6V.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjbJi.png

This happens around the same minute at different hours, so I don't believe it's client initiated. Looks like it happens when the server makes it's scheduled cleanup.

Since DHCP is set to dynamically update DNS, when it expires the lease it will remove the DNS entry, and the machine can't be found by name on the network. If the machine is rebooted or if we run ipconfig /renew, the same IP is leased again. The lease expiration time is correctly set both on the server and on the client, but the lease is "randomly" expired anyway.

What can be causing this lease to expire?

Some more info that can be useful:

We have DHCP failover configured in as hot-standby. The primary is active and there was no outage of any of them recently.

Comment: DHCP failover requires that both DHCP servers receive all DHCP messages. If this is not the case, DHCP gives you temporary lease of 1 hour.

Is your DHCP helper/relay configured with both failover nodes?

Comment: Yes! We have boths servers set as helper addresses. The lease expiration timestamp is correctly set both at the server and at the client, 8 days from "now".